# Why should I use a debug build?

Tags: android, debugging, build, release

I have a simple question:

Why should I use the debug configuration in Android Apps?

The reason for my question is that I ran into some release-only bugs which could be totally avoided if I always debug my code in the release variant.

So in the release build I just set the debuggable flag to true and disable ProGuard during debugging. -> Problem gone.

(I still have to test it once with ProGuard enabled of course...)

Are there any arguments against my approach? If not, why does a debug build exist then?

A collection of arguments for the debug variant according to other answers:

- ProGuard (ok...this is no argument)
- build speed (for some reason my release variant takes less time to compile...)
- API-keys (one user more or less doesn't matter...)
- debuggable (this also works in the release build)
- debug-only permissions (I can uncomment this one line in the manifest...)
- signing certificate (this doesn't really matter...)

Please give me something that makes me use the debug variant, otherwise I will ban it from my apps^^

Comment: `set the debuggable flag to true and disable ProGuard` this is a debug build itself in fact. You just made release build a debug build. There is totally no difference between release and debug except anything that you set in gradle (disable debugging, enable proguard, select certificate, etc)

Comment: but why does a debug build exist then? Or why are there different API-keys and apk-signing-keys? I don't get the whole idea of a debug build^^

Comment: because it is a default android project template. The `debug` is just a name for the `buildType`, same as `release`,`staging`,`production`,`myAvesomeBuildType`. There is nothing special in it.

Comment: ok thanks I get it :) But why do I have to use different API-keys?

Comment: When I remember correctly, the debug build splits the build in two parts, one generic part which is deployed only once, and a small project part, which is deployed each time. This speeds up performance when deploying to a device for debugging. Why the release build should be faster I do not know. (Maybe this only applies to Xamarin projects though)

Comment: that is because of signing. If you don't provide signing config, it will use a default config, and sign it with a default *debug* certificate. That is the only reason.

Comment: So I don't need a debug API-key after release anymore because I could  just sign any build type with the same signing config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In smaller projects a debug build can seem like an overkill. Like stated in the comments it is exactly the same as a release build when you turn of proguard and enable debugging. It's just a template for an Android project which allows you to quickly setup 2 types of builds.

Once you work on bigger projects this functionality gets more interesting. You will set up a build server which triggers automated builds on a regular basis so you won't have to manually configure your gradle file each time you want a specific type of build. 
Next to debug and release you might even want to create more more configurations, each connecting to different test environments so testers can work without having to contact you each time they need a different build. You also mention the build times to be shorter on release but once your project gets big and you include e.g. Dexguard to obfuscate it will take a very long time each time you want to build and you'll love having debug builds to speed up your development